# How to present Popover modal in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, popover

Could someone help me to create popover in ReactJS UI, Something like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easy using one of the popular ui component frameworks. For example bootstrap/jquery.

Follow the steps below and you will be fine:

1. In `render` method of the parent component prepare html layout in accordance with [guidelines for the component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers):

`<a href="#" id="mypopover" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>`

2. In componentDidMount method of the parent component:

`$("#mypopover").popover();`

3. And finally in `componentWillUnmount`:

`$("#mypopover").popover('destroy')`